# Adding Custom PHTML file in List.phtml (Category View)

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, phtml, list.phtml

I have a custom PHTML file

```
custom_theme/default/template/catalog/product/colors.phtml
```

I have edited

```
custom_theme/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

I have added

```
<block type="catalog/product_colors" name="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml"/>
```

Right under list.phtml as follows

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_colors" name="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml"/>
```

I have added

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('colors') ?>
```

to

```
custom_theme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Nothing is showing on the category page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you created block `Colors` ? as you have used `block type="catalog/product_colors"`

Comment: I've only done what I mentioned. What do I need to do?

Comment: what is in `catalog/product/colors.phtml` file ??

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code

```
 <block type="catalog/product_colors" name="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml"/>
```

with

```
<block type="core/template" name="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml"/>
```

and try after clearing cache.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**
That colors.phtml file can be called directly in list.phtml file without creating block in catalog.xml by adding this following code in list.phtml.

```
<?php echo $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/colors.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

**Method 2:**
Replace your line with

```
<block type="core/template" name="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml" />
```

Note: Now check where do u want to make it display for Catalog Category (Anchor) or Catalog Category (Non-Anchor) or for both. Then add that line accordingly.

Now call that block in list.phtml file by adding bellow line.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('colors'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `catalog/product_colors` block does not exit at default magento.

You need to changed it to **core/template**,in order to check  **catalog/product/colors.phtml** render at **category view page page**.

Also note that you should add this block both two handler `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`

```
<block type="catalog/product_colors" name="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml"/>
```

Comment: The data in colors.phtml is item specific and i need to show this inside the product foreach loop in list.phtml. Is this possible? I need this as I need to stop full page cache from caching it and I need a block name. Can this be created inside list.phtml itself? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not created block `Colors`. This is needed because you have used `block type="catalog/product_colors"`.

Change

```
<block type="catalog/product_colors" name="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml"/>
```

TO

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="colors" as="colors" template="catalog/product/colors.phtml"/>
```

You can also use `block type="core/template"`

Comment: thanks. What if `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('colors') ?>`is inside a foreach loop. how do I get it to display the correct value per product?